# cant get GET parameters for a cakephp3 search function

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I am converting a cakephp2 search function to cakephp3. I convert post parameters  to get parameters . I get the correct parameters appearing as a query string in the address bar but when I access the variables in the for loop below I get no output. I cant see what I am doing wrong and I cant find the answer in the docs.

How do I get the GET parameters in the foreach loop below in cakephp3?

```
     if ($this->request->is('post')) {


         $filter_url['controller'] = $this->request->params['controller'];
           $filter_url['action'] = $this->request->params['action'];
           $filter_url['page'] = 1;

    // for each filter we will add a GET parameter for the generated url
    foreach($this->request->data as $name => $value){
       if($value){
           $filter_url[$name] = urlencode($value);
       }
    }   
    //Post params are now GET paramaters
    return $this->redirect($filter_url);


    } 




 debug($this->request->params['pass'] ); //outputs nothing


       foreach($this->request->params['pass'] as $param_name => $value):
        // debug($param_name);
           //    debug($value);
            if ($param_name=='lastname')  $searchLastName =$value;
            if ($param_name=='firstname')  $searchFirstName =$value;


        endforeach;

//view
 <?php echo $this->Form->create(); ?>
     <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
        <thead>
            <tr>


                <td><?php   echo $this->Form->input('firstname',['label' => 'FirstName']); ?></td>
                 <td><?php   echo $this->Form->input('lastname',['label' => ' LastName']); ?></td>
                <td> <?php //echo $this->Form->button('Submit Form', ['name'=>'search','type' => 'submit']); ?></td>
            </tr>
        </thead>

    <?= $this->Form->button('Submit Form', ['name'=>'search','type' => 'submit']); ?>
    <?= $this->Form->end() ?>

http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/request-response.html
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked

```
 foreach($this->request->query as $param_name => $value):

                if ($param_name=='lastname')  $searchLastName =$value;
                if ($param_name=='firstname')  $searchFirstName =$value;


            endforeach;
```